# deal with black-box on predictive model in data science

Tags: testing, model, statistics

I have a question about this kind of situation.
If I have a black-box which contain only the code for one specific model,like Support Vector Machine,with no any other information in the box.

How should I test the model is still effective to use or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

-first figure out if it works and how to train and generate predictions

-then pick a couple of datasets and divide it into your training and test data

-train and test the blackbox model and compare the results with a couple of known models

*the point to stress here* is to make sure you don't train your model(s) with your testing data...because that's the true test of how the model will generalize. If you're new to modelling, this is the most important thing.

It is common that certain models do well on some types of data and not others so that's the trick here...finding where the blackbox can be effective.

If your goal is to try and figure out the model in the box, then select datasets known to favour certain models and if it does well on it you can have an educated guess. But tricky to say for sure.

Not knowing the type of model is not good because it can be a time-waster if you are running a bunch of different algorithms on some data...you don't want to duplicate your efforts and it's nice to know how it can be regularized(unless it does that for you).